# Create git repo on remote in existing project, then clone it

Tags: git

I think it's pretty much all there in the title. I've got an existing project on a remote vps that I'd like to track with git, but I'm not sure the correct process. Do I need to create a bare repo on the server, then grab all the files, initialise them on local, then push them back up to the remote?
Or is there another way to do it, i.e. somehow track the remote files, then clone to local?

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure what you wanna achieve but from my understanding...
First go to the root of your existing project on your vps and do:

```
git init
```

In your github account, create a new repo and copy the ssh link to the newly created repo (if you have authenticated your device, else use the https link), it looks something like: "git@github.com:your_username/your_project_name.git"

Then on your existing vps project do:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:your_username/your_project_name.git
git add -A
git commit -m 'init'
git push origin master
```

If you want to install and track the project from another device just do:

```
git clone git@github.com:your_username/your_project_name.git
```

And you will have a copy of the project.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yeah that's it. Thanks